# How are permissions inherited on an Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, system-administration

Sorry for the second newbie question, I'm a developer not a sysadmin so this is all quite new to me. I hope I can explain myself clearly! Here goes.

Here's what I did:

- **Logged into the root account**
- Created the accounts 'richard' and 'austin'
- Created the group 'developers', and added 'richard' and 'austin' to it
- Created the directory /server, and used "chown richard:developers /server" to change the owner
- Changed the permissions of /server to drwxrwxr-x (so the group can write to it)
- **Logged out of the root account, and into the 'richard' account**
- Created the directories /server/production and /server/staging
- Used "ls -l" inside /server to list the contents, and found permissions of drwxr-xr-x and ownership of "richard:richard" for both /server/production and /server/staging. Consequently, 'austin' can edit inside the /server directory, but not inside the directories 'richard' created.

What am I doing wrong? I want to ensure that any files or folders created inside the /server directory have group write permissions and belong to the developers group. How do I go about that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to use "chmod g+s" or "chmode 2775" to get the SetGID bit set on the directory, that should preserve the group if I remember my permission modes properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you created the directories as richard the system assumed that you were the owner and set you as the owner, you can either change the ownership and permissions manualy

```
sudo chown richard:developers
sudo chmod 775
```

or
set the default permissions for creating files/folders (found this: http://wiki.slicehost.com/doku.php?id=setting_up_ubuntu_slice_with_django_postgresql_ledgersmb_and_openvpn)
or
use acl's (see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3718480&postcount=12) for details

Answer (score 0):

How did you change the permissions of /server? Do it recursively, if you didn't.

Good luck!

Comment: So...

"chown -R richard:developers /server"
"chmod -R g+w /server"

Will that automatically apply those permissions to new files and directories? If so, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you must have set a restrictive umask

edit ~/.bash_profile

and modify the umask setting for the specific user.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask